# Cycle a list of audio files on click

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a simple code that plays a list of audio files by clicking each button.  This works fine but what I need to 1 button that cycles through the list each time the button is pressed.

I.e.
Click Button = play sound 1
Click again plays sound 2
Click again plays sound 3 etc.

```js
const sounds = ['sound1', 'sound2', 'sound3', 'sound4', 'sound5', 'sound6'];

sounds.forEach(sound => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.classList.add('btn');
    btn.innerText = sound;

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        stopPlaying();
        document.getElementById(sound).play();
    })

    document.getElementById('buttons').append(btn);
})


function stopPlaying() {
    sounds.forEach(sound => {
        const audio = document.getElementById(sound);
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    })
}
```

Comment: <body>
    <audio src="sound1.mp3" id="sound1"></audio>
    <audio src="sound2.mp3" id="sound2"></audio>
    <audio src="sound3.mp3" id="sound3"></audio>
    <audio src="sound4.mp3" id="sound4"></audio>
    <audio src="sound5.mp3" id="sound5"></audio>
    <audio src="sound6.mp3" id="sound6"></audio>

    <div id="buttons"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

Comment: Currently, I have 6 buttons but want to combine them into 1 button that cycles the sounds

Comment: Thats the question that I'm asking.....  If I knew that I wouldn't be here....

Answer (score 1):

use an array.

```js
var audios = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
var pointer = 0;
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.classList.add('btn');
btn.innerText = "play next";

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // stopPlaying();
  audios[pointer].play();
  console.log("playing " + audios[pointer].getAttribute("src"))
  
  pointer += 1;
  if (pointer >= audios.length) {
    pointer = 0
  }
})

document.body.append(btn)
```

```html
<audio src="song1.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="song2.mp3"></audio>
```